# How to Cast a String Dynamically to other type java

Tags: java

i have a legacy classes with all the fields declared as strings and binded to UI fields, so that it can accept the user input. but in some cases user can enter a number values for few fields, these are also getting stored into a string.
Now i have a requirement to sort the objects based on the field. i am trying this using a reflection to make it common across the module. for the above scenario i am passing the data type name from front end and trying to cast dynamically as follows

```
private static Object typeCastAs(String type, Object obj){
        Object result = null;
        try{
            Class _Class = Class.forName(type);
            Object obj1  = (Object) obj;
            result = _Class.cast(obj1);
        }
        catch(ClassNotFoundException ignore){
            System.out.println("Catch exception");
        }
        return result;
    }
```

But when i try to typecast it to integer it throws **ClassCastException** since the actual value is stored in String even though it is integer
Is there any alternate solution for this requirement

Comment: Are you looking for something like [`Integer.parseInt()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#parseInt(java.lang.String)) ?

Comment: Can you send the parameters you are passing to this function.

Answer (score 1):

You must parse the `String` to an `Integer` using [`Integer.valueOf(String s)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-).

```
Integer i = Integer.valueOf(string);
```

This can not be done by reflection, you must write logic.

Comment: Tichodroma this will work for Integers alone, i want this thing to work for all  data types as a common thing

Comment: Yes, of course this works only for `Integer`. You must use the existing methods of ther wrapper classes to parse a `String`. Just casting is not enough.

Comment: yes, So is there a way to make it generic i mean casting it to the passed type dynamically

Comment: @Siva, the short answer is no.  The long answer is noooooooo.

Answer (score 1):

I'm using the [Apache Commons BeanUtils library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/) for this. It probably does everything you need. And if you are missing something you can add your own converters.

To start, have a look at the [BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.9.2/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) class.

Comment: This specific class would be a useful - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-beanutils/javadocs/v1.8.3/apidocs/index.html